# How do I get rid of these things in intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Red box around text]

I'm looking to get rid off these helper texts. I do not know what they are called so I don't know what setting I need to remove. I'm sure it's just some check box that needs to be unchecked.

What are these called so that I can turn them on and off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inlay Hints | Code Vision | Usages.

Comment: So much cleaner. Thanks